# How to know the model name of one device name and vice versa?

Tags: device-name

Let's say we have `Nexus 7 2013` tablet which has model name to be `NEXUS7-2B32`.

I have difficulties in choosing the device items on ebay - the right model to buy only came from model name, not from the title/text name given by the sellers.

So my question is, where would we Anroid users can see the list of model name and its marketing/device name accoringly?

Answer (score 1):

PDF at this link may help you [List of all devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

There is also `.csv` available

Devices are listed in the following format - Marketing Name (Build.os.DEVICE/Build.os.MODEL)

Against your query of *Nexus 7 2013*, it returns two occurrences

Retail Name : Asus

Marketing Name: Nexus 7 (2013)

Device : deb

Model : Nexus 7

and

Retail Name : Asus

Marketing Name: Nexus 7 (2013)

Device : flo

Model : Nexus 7

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718532/a-complete-list-of-all-android-devices

Please do update your question if you locate alternative

**Edit**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587867/where-do-i-get-a-list-of-build-model-names-for-all-android-devices)
mentions a couple of git-hub sources which have device name information listed and this may help (I don't know how to get information from there )

- https://github.com/mataanin/android-devices and
- https://github.com/meetup/android-device-names

Comment: Well, `flo` or `deb` is not what we see around the market e.g. http://www.ebay.com/itm/Asus-Google-Nexus-7-2013-2nd-Gen-16GB-Wi-Fi-Tablet-Used-Fair-Cond/221960921402?_trksid=p2045573.c100505.m3226&_trkparms=aid%3D555014%26algo%3DPL.DEFAULT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150817211623%26meid%3D8f6897b450ff4b0289cb954bc442fbe0%26pid%3D100505%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26

Comment: Agreed..that's why I said it "may" be useful. Come to think of it, at least in one place have all devices listed and available. Thanks for asking, it helped me too. Please do update if you find what you or we are looking for

Comment: Yeah sure I'll post the info when I found it.